# Who else is both an X-man and an Avenger?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men, avengers

I [know](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/13019/3804) that Beast is both a member of the X-men, and a (Secret) Avenger. Is there anyone else who is a current Avenger member as well as being a current X-man?

<sub>Ex-members of either don't count unless they were a member of both teams at some point (i.e. I'm excluding people who left one team only to join the other later)</sub>.

Comment: Is `X-man` correct term?

Comment: Do you mean Avenger as in official team member, or just fight on their side in AvX?

Comment: @DVK Official card carrying members.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wolverine and Storm (recently Avengers 21 (2012)) are both current Avengers.

4/12/12: Storm left the Avengers to fight on Cyclops's side in the AvX storyline. [Marvel Wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/List_of_Avengers_members) has a list of all Avengers ever which does include Namor the Sub-Mariner who was not a member of both teams at the same time.

Comment: Is that an exhaustive list?

Answer (score 2):

Rogue is pretty regularly seen in both capacities in the "X-Men" and "Uncanny Avengers" titles.

Deadpool is a reserve member of the Great Lakes Avengers and active in X-Force, if that counts.